# If a belongs to R then prove that (-a)=-(a) using algebraic properties of R

Tags: real-analysis

I could prove -1(a) = -(a) but somewhere I needed the fact that 1/(-a).-(a)= 1 which can be proved by multiplicative identity only when (-a) = -(a)

Comment: Welcome. Probably it is a dupe(you can find the same question elsewhere on MathStackExchange), already answered :  $\forall a \in \Bbb R, (-1)a+a=(-1)a+1a=[(-1)+1]a=0a=0$

Answer (score 0):

There is no semantic difference between (-a) and -(a), so this is pretty much a tautology. In general, $x=(x)$ for any $x$, so we have

$(-a)=-a=-(a)$

where the last equality follows from $a=(a)$.